# Is "due to" usage correct in the given sentence?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

> Unfortunately, your booking is rejected **due to** you had another
>   appointment on the same day.

Is the above usage of **due to** correct grammar-wise? I have a feeling it makes more sense to say something like

> Unfortunately, your booking is rejected **due to the fact that** you had another
>   appointment on the same day.

or

> Unfortunately, your booking is rejected **simply because** you had another
>   appointment on the same day.

Please help me understand why the original sentence is/is not correct. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the sentence *Unfortunately, your booking is rejected due to you had another appointment on the same day* is **not correct**.

*Due to* is used with a noun or a noun phrase (not a clause). For example,

1. Due to injury, the team captain was forced to withdraw from the match.
2. The bus was delayed due to heavy snow.

*Due to* can be substituted by *because of* or *owing to*. So, if you say *due to + the fact + that*, it's absolutely correct.